# Simple pattern recognition from paper: knowledge test

Tags: android, opencv, pattern-recognition

I want to make an app for test validation (on paper) with the camera (ex. android). Accordingly, I need to recognize filled response options on a paper, which I will do in advance.

Prompt, where to start? Where to dig? 
I know of the existence of the library OpenCV - it will help me?

Thank you.

Comment: For me the best you can do is start playing with some QRCode lib to understand how the pattern recognize works for pictures...

Comment: So it's some kind of multiple choice, no need to recognize handwritten words, right?

Comment: I'd rather recommend heading into OpenCV than a QRCode lib.

Comment: FD_, right, only multiple choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV will definitely get you there.

Have a look at this tutorial: http://blog.ayoungprogrammer.com/2013/03/tutorial-creating-multiple-choice.html